# confusion over mocking in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

what I don't get in mocking in unit test is first of all why do is what does the following method do exactly

```
var tt = new PortfolioData()
{
    CurrentTotalValue = 200121,
    Stocks = stocksTemp
};

mock
    .Setup(p => p.GetPortfolio("61377666d24fd78398a5a558"))
    .ReturnsAsync(tt);
```

I think it says run the `GetPotfolio` method pass the string and return the `tt`. But again after this method, we need to test the controller, why?

```
var sut = new PortfolioController(mock.Object);
```

What is `mock.Object` here? I really don't get it

Comment: `mock.Object` returns a mocked representation of the type being mocked within `Mock<T>`. You pass/inject that into the subject under test in order to verify the expected behavior

Comment: `mock.Setup` configures the expectation of the member being mocked. In your example, when ever the mock invokes `GetPortfolio("61377666d24fd78398a5a558")` then `tt` will be returned. Anything else will return null since nothing else was configured to be expected. Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)
to get a better understanding of the MOQ library

Answer (score 0):

In order to give you explanation let's suppose that your controller has been implemented in the following way:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PortfolioController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPortfolioService service;
    public PortfolioController(IPortfolioService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        var data = await service.GetPortfolio(id);
        if (data != null)
            return Ok();
        else
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

Depending on the result of the `GetPortfolio` your controller will return either `200` or `404`.

By mocking the `service` you can deterministically say that *In this particular test case the service should always return x*. If that's true then you can make assertion on the result of the controller's action.

You can write a test, which assures that if the controller's action receives a `PortfolioData` then it will return 200

```
public async Task GivenAnIdWithARelatedPortofolioData_WhenICallGet_ThenTheContollerReturnsOk()
{
    //Arrange
    var serviceMock = new Mock<IPortfolioService>();
    const string expectedId = "61377666d24fd78398a5a558";
    var expectedResult = new PortfolioData()
    {
        CurrentTotalValue = 200121,
        Stocks = stocksTemp
    };

    serviceMock
        .Setup(p => p.GetPortfolio(expectedId))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);

    var sut = new PortfolioController(serviceMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await sut.Get(expectedId);

    //Assert
    var actionResult = result as OkResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
}
```

You can also write test for the other branch. If the `GetPortofolio` does not return an object  (the setup condition does not meet then it will return `null`) the controller will return Not found.

```
public async Task GivenAnIdWithoutARelatedPortofolioData_WhenICallGet_ThenTheContollerReturnsNotFound()
{
    //Arrange
    var serviceMock = new Mock<IPortfolioService>();
    var expectedId = "61377666d24fd78398a5a558";
    var expectedResult = new PortfolioData()
    {
        CurrentTotalValue = 200121,
        Stocks = stocksTemp
    };

    serviceMock
        .Setup(p => p.GetPortfolio(expectedId))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);

    var sut = new PortfolioController(serviceMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await sut.Get(expectedId + "1");

    //Assert
    var actionResult = result as StatusCodeResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
    Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, actionResult.StatusCode)
}
```

So in these cases the

- `serviceMock`'s type is `Mock<IPortfolioService>`
- `serviceMock.Object`'s type is `IPortfolioService`

The `PortfolioController` controller expects an `IPortfolioService`, that's why you need to provide the `serviceMock.Object`.